# Hosting provider blocks webservice response - (1and1 hosting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webservice-client

I have an application written in ASP.NET MVC 4. I got access to remote web service. I added it to my solution as WebReference. When i call it's methods on my localhost all works great, the problem is on deployed version. Server provider run it as "Medium Trust". When i call WebService methods from hosted application i got an error:

[image]

I think the problem is in firewall rules on hosting server, my binding type for the service is "basicHttpBinding" with defaults settings. In this case my listening port is random, so how i can get through it? How to set static listening port for WebService response, so i can ask hosing provider to set firewall port open for my application?

My binding config:

```
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://WebServiceURL:8585/Api" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IETRService" contract="ETRService.IETRService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IETRService"  />
    </client>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy, you should be listening on a standard port, I would assume (remove the port :8585) from your local testing in order to connect to your server.

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://WebServiceURL/Api" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IETRService" contract="ETRService.IETRService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IETRService"  />
</client>
```

Comment: I'm not an owner of this WebService... I need to connect to it. So i can't change the listening port of service.

Comment: Gotcha, that part was unclear.  I thought you had developed the API.  If the API is listening on that port, you will need to contact customer support in order to open that up outbound

Comment: Or maybe i can use a proxy to connect to it? I don't really know because that is my 1st try with API's ;) Every advice would be great.

Comment: So the problem is solved, my server provider blocked my communication on their proxy server. Now everything is clear but thx for help ;)